# Rails 4.0 redirects to 404 even though data exists

Tags: mysql, redirect, http-status-code-404, ruby-on-rails-4, null

When I was running through my rails show page in Rails 4.0, I noticed that each time no matter if the id is nil or not, it redirects towards the 404.html page. While this is good and all for the nil ones, the ones that do have data appear to redirect to the same thing. So if I say page localhost/accounts/gmills@gome.com it redirects to the 404 page even though it exists in my database. I want to have email or username be used instead to differentiate users than to use just use the id field.

I could use your advice on how to solve this and make it work so that it only goes to 404 on the nil pages only in Rails 4.0.

**MYSQL Database**

```
MySQL Table account

id      first_name     last_name    email
1       gill       mills    gmills@gome.com
2       jib        jab          jjab@morris.com
```

**Accounts Controller**

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :html
      before_filter :load_findaccount, :only => [:show, :edit, :update]

   def index #Displays all of the names that are stored in the database
      @accounts = Account.all
   end

   def new #allows the creation of new Name accounts
      @account = Account.new
      #new_account_path(:first_name
   end

   def create
      @account =Account.new(account_params)

      #@account = Account.new(params[:account])

      if @account.save
         redirect_to @account
      else
         render "new"
      end
   end

   def show
      @account = Account.find_by_email(params[:id])
      if @account.nil?
         render "shared/404"
      else
         respond_with(@account)
      end
   end


   private
      # Using a private method to encapsulate the permissible parameters is
      # just a good pattern since you'll be able to reuse the same permit
      # list between create and update. Also, you can specialize this method
      # with per-user checking of permissible attributes.
      def account_params
         params.require(:account).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email)
      end

      def load_findaccount
         #params[:id] remains fixed but find_by_id changes to username
         #@account = Account.find_by(params[:id])
         #user_path(user)
      end
end


#   def create
#      @groupee = Groupee.new(params[:groupee])

 #     if @groupee.save
 #        session[:groupee_id] = @groupee.id
 #        flash[:success] = "Welcome #{@groupee.username} to MusicBand"
 #        redirect_to @groupee, :notice => "Groupee Account successfully created." #Changing users to user redirects to a specific user page
 #     else
 #        render "new"
 #     end
 #  end
```

**Account Model**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

       def to_param  # overridden
          email
       end


   validates :first_name, :presence => true
   validates :last_name, :presence => true
   validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness =>{:case_sensitive => false}
end
```

**Show View**

```
<h1>Displays a specific name_account on the server</h1>

<h1>First_name</h1>
<%= @account.first_name %>
<h1>Last_name</h1>
<%= @account.last_name %>
<h1>Email</h1>
<%= @account.email %>
```

**Index View**

```
<h1>Displays all of the name_accounts on the server</h1>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>First_name</td>
      <td>Last_name</td>
      <td>Email</td>
   </tr>
<% @accounts.each do |account| %>
   <tr>
      <td><%= account.first_name %></td>
      <td><%= account.last_name %></td>
      <td><%= account.email %></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

**404 page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>The page you were looking for doesn't exist (404)</title>
  <style>
  body {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    color: #2E2F30;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  }

  div.dialog {
    width: 25em;
    margin: 4em auto 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-right-color: #999;
    border-left-color: #999;
    border-bottom-color: #BBB;
    border-top: #B00100 solid 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 9px;
    border-top-right-radius: 9px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 7px 4em 0 4em;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #730E15;
    line-height: 1.5em;
  }

  body > p {
    width: 33em;
    margin: 0 auto 1em;
    padding: 1em 0;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-right-color: #999;
    border-bottom-color: #999;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-color: #DADADA;
    color: #666;
    box-shadow:0 3px 8px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.17);
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- This file lives in public/404.html -->
  <div class="dialog">
    <h1>The page you were looking for doesn't exist.</h1>
    <p>You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.</p>
  </div>
  <p>If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by going back to a previous version of rails. Rails 4.0 is not strong enough and is still in beta, so Rails 3.2.13 is the one I am using now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have overridden `to_param`, so you can use the email in the parameters instead of the id.  Try using a puts statement in the show action to inspect the params.  My guess is that you need to use `params[:email]`, not `params[:id]`.

```
   def show
      puts "*************************"
      puts params
      @account = Account.find_by_email(params[:email])
      if @account.nil?
         render "shared/404"
      else
         respond_with(@account)
      end
   end
```

Comment: Well I tried that a couple of time but I didn't get anywhere. the problem with using find_by_email is that syntax is rails 3.0 not rails 4.0. I tried both formats and it still didn't work. I still get sent to the same location which is that page goes to an error page and the puts don't display anything.